# Trying to import an android project built on Android studio into eclipse is throwing an error?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to import an existing android project which is built on Android studio into eclipse as `Import->Gradle project->`

When I click on Build Model it is giving me a following error.

I have attached screen shot:

[image]

The console output:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> The SDK directory 'C:\Users\Pritam Singh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.747 secs

Comment: Did you check in the project settings if the SDK location is correctly set? `Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK`

Comment: Under preferences I can only see Appearance.
Can you elaborate more please. I'm new to android don't min.

Comment: Can't you expand it? Which version of Androud Studio are you using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse, but the project was built using android studio on some body else system. so the sdk path of that system is set into the project.

Comment: My question is, is there any way to change sdk location before I import into my eclipse?

Comment: go back to eclipse -and forget studio

Comment: The project I'm trying to import has a different location and my system sdk is at different location.